# htaccess redirect of root domain, not subfolders with url masking

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to do the following -

Redirect just the root domain to a different domain.
The redirect needs to be masked so the user still thinks they are on the url they typed.
Existing subfolders should still work with the existing root domain.

For example-

I have an installation using www.currentsite.com which has lots of subfolders for example www.currentsite.com/store
I want to redirect just the root of www.currentsite.com to www.newsite.com but want the browser to still say www.currentsite.com.
If the user goes to www.currentsite.com/subfolder I still want that to work with the original installation.

I have the following which seems to be handling redirecting just the root fine but does not mask the url...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.currentsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.co.uk/ [L,R=301]
```

Any help id appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For what you call "masked" the usage of apaches proxy module makes most sense:

```
ProxyPass https://www.currentsite.com https://www.newsite.co.uk
ProxyPassReverse https://www.currentsite.com https://www.newsite.co.uk
```

It maps one base url to another one and takes care to transparently and reliably rewrite all contained references.

The proxy module can also be used by RewriteRules, the `P` flag does that. But in the end it comes out itself and the above, direct usage is more transparent and less complex.

Here is the documentation, as typical for the apache project it is of excellent quality and comes with lots of good examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html